# Sort an array of object by a property (with custom order, not alphabetically)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to get your help about this little problem.

I have like to order this array depending on the *code* value **but not in alphabetical order.**
(*I specified this in bold but got eventually flagged anyway, people don't even care about reading the question*)

For example I would like to have all the *green* objects, then all the *blue* ones and then all the *red* ones. What is the best way to do that?

```
[
    { code: "RED", value: 0},
    { code: "BLUE", value: 0},
    { code: "RED", value: 0},
    { code: "GREEN", value: 0},
    { code: "BLUE", value: 0},
    { code: "RED", value: 0},
    { code: "GREEN", value: 0},
    { code: "BLUE", value: 0}
]
```

Is it possible to do that with the *sort* function? What would the condition be in that case?

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst I just looped through the array, I wanted to see if there was a faster way.

Comment: @lilezek please read the question before flagging, **I DON'T WANT IT TO BE ALPHABETICALLY ORDERED**

Comment: @LucaDeNardi You just have to write your own sorting function, literally.

Comment: @lilezek not true at all, since someone provided a faster way to do that.

Comment: @LucaDeNardi everyone here provided a sorting function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could take an object for the wanted order.

```js
var array = [{ code: "RED", value: 0 }, { code: "BLUE", value: 0 }, { code: "RED", value: 0 }, { code: "GREEN", value: 0 }, { code: "BLUE", value: 0 }, { code: "RED", value: 0 }, { code: "GREEN", value: 0 }, { code: "BLUE", value: 0 }],
    order = { GREEN: 1, BLUE: 2, RED: 3 };
    
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return order[a.code] - order[b.code];
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For unknow colors/values, you could use a default value with

- `0`, for sorting to top or
- `Infinity` or as some suggest because of the ability for caculating [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) for sorting to the end,
- or any other value for sorting inbetween the other groups.

At last you could sort the special treated items with an other sorting part, chained with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

```js
var array = [{ code: "YELLOW", value: 0 }, { code: "BLACK", value: 0 }, { code: "RED", value: 0 }, { code: "BLUE", value: 0 }, { code: "RED", value: 0 }, { code: "GREEN", value: 0 }, { code: "BLUE", value: 0 }, { code: "RED", value: 0 }, { code: "GREEN", value: 0 }, { code: "BLUE", value: 0 }],
    order = { GREEN: 1, BLUE: 2, RED: 3, default: Infinity };
    
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (order[a.code] || order.default) - (order[b.code] || order.default) || a.code.localeCompare(b.code);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Mmm this is interesting! I didn't think about using an object to keep track of the order :)

Answer (score 3):

Set the custom priority first

```
var codePriority = [ "GREEN", "BLUE", "RED" ];
```

Now use the same in sorting as

```
arr.sort( function(a,b){ 
   if ( a.code == b.code ) return a.value - b.value;
   return codePriority.indexOf( a.code ) - codePriority.indexOf( b.code ) ; notice this line
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [
    { code: "RED", value: 0},
    { code: "BLUE", value: 0},
    { code: "RED", value: 0},
    { code: "GREEN", value: 0},
    { code: "BLUE", value: 0},
    { code: "RED", value: 0},
    { code: "GREEN", value: 0},
    { code: "BLUE", value: 0}
];
var codePriority = [ "GREEN", "BLUE", "RED" ];
arr.sort( function(a,b){ 
   if ( a.code == b.code ) return a.value - b.value;
   return codePriority.indexOf( a.code ) - codePriority.indexOf( b.code )
});
console.log( arr );
```

Comment: You can remove the `if` check. Try `return codePriority.indexOf( a.code ) - codePriority.indexOf( b.code ) || a.value - b.value`

Comment: @Rajesh ohh, didn't thought of that :)... I would keep this as is for now, its more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a schema array and sort according to element's index inside that schema array.

```js
const a = ['GREEN', 'BLUE', 'RED'];

const o = [{code:"RED",value:0},{code:"BLUE",value:0},{code:"RED",value:0},{code:"GREEN",value:0},{code:"BLUE",value:0},{code:"RED",value:0},{code:"GREEN",value:0},{code:"BLUE",value:0}];

const r = o.slice().sort(({ code: q }, { code: w }) => a.indexOf(q) - a.indexOf(w));

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a function for sorting by a specific color.

```js
const colors = [{
    name: "T-shirt",
    color: "red",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Shoes",
    color: "yellow",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Pants",
    color: "red",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Cap",
    color: "yellow",
    price: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Skirt",
    color: "red",
    price: 15
  },
]

let sortByColor = color => colors.sort((a, b) => a.color === color ? -1 : 1)

console.log(sortByColor('red'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sort function i.e Array.prototype.sort() Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Firstly you have to decide whether you want to sort in ascending order or in descending order.
To sort in ascending order you can do something like this:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.color < b.color ? -1 : a.color > b.color ? 1 : 0;
  });
```

An to do it in descending order:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.color > b.color ? -1 : a.color < b.color ? 1 : 0;
  });
```

Now  suppose you want a certain color sorted and displayed first. You can have a function like this:

```
const sortByKeyAsc = (arr,color) =>
  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a.color < b.color || (a.color === color && b.color !== color)){
      return -1;
    }
    if(a.color > b.color || (a.color !== color && b.color === color)){
      return 1
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

and you can use it like this:

```
const array1 = sortByKeyAsc(arr,'pink');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a case where I had to match a string status and sort by the various statuses specifically. `.findIndex` and `.includes` ended up being the best approach.

statusPriority sets the intended order. Once the indexes are found they can be compared and returned to the .sort

```js
let records = [
  {status: 'Record is ready to submit.', active: true, name: 'A'},
  {status: 'Record has been sent.', active: true, name: 'B'},
  {status: 'Activation is required.', active: true, name: 'C'},
  {status: 'Record submission failed.', active: true, name: 'D'},
  {status: 'Creation is pending.', active: true, name: 'E'},
]

console.log(records.map(r => r.status))

let statusPriority = ['creation', 'activation', 'sent', 'ready', 'failed'];
records.sort((a, b) => {
  let aIndex = statusPriority.findIndex(status => a.status.toLowerCase().includes(status));
  let bIndex = statusPriority.findIndex(status => b.status.toLowerCase().includes(status));
  return aIndex - bIndex;
})

console.log(records.map(r => r.status))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort color alphabetically by using this function

```
  var sortedArr = arr.sort((first, second)=>{
            
        return first.color < second.color ? -1 : 1
    })
```